# Extracting jpeg files from file in C

Tags: c, file-io, jpeg

I am trying to extract jpeg files from a memory-card like file. The program will read 512 byte blocks at a time and if the block starts with JPEG-identifying bytes, my program should write to an output file those bytes. It should keep writing those bytes until it finds another JPEG-identifying byte sequence at which time it should stop writing to the .jpg file and write to a new one. Each file should be named 00x.jpg where x is the #.

My program compiles but doesn't produce all the jpegs. There should be 16 JPEGs but it only produces 7.

```
int main(void)
{
    // open file for reading
    FILE* file = fopen("card.raw", "r"); // Open the file for reading

    // target file
    FILE* image;

    // buffer of bytes
    uint8_t buffer[512];        

    // check for NULL file
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fclose(file);
        printf("Could not open file");
        return 1;
    }

    // Prefixes of a jpeg file
    uint8_t jpeg1[4] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe0};
    uint8_t jpeg2[4] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe1};

    // keep track of jpegs opened
    int pic = 0;

    int match = 0;

    // is file open?
    int open = 0;


    // stores first 4 bytes of block
    uint8_t check[4];

    int byteNum;
    byteNum = fread(buffer, 512, 1, file);

    // while there are bytes to be read in the file
    while(fread(buffer,512, 1, file) > 0)
    {
        for (int x=0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            check[x] = buffer[x];
        }

        // compares first 4 bytes of buffer segment to jpeg prefixes to determine match
        if((memcmp(check, jpeg1,4) == 0) || (memcmp(check, jpeg2, 4) == 0))
        {

            match = 1;   
        }
        // if encounter a jpeg and file is open, close the file and set match to false
        if (match == 1 && open == 1)
        {


            fclose(image);
            open = 0;        
            match = 0;
        }

        // if match is true and file is closed, create jpeg output file, increment pic#, set file to open, set match to false, open target file
        if (match == 1 && open == 0)
        {
            // stores name of jpegfile
            char jpegName[8]; 
            // stores the jpeg file name with the # jpeg          
            sprintf(jpegName ,"%03d.jpg" ,pic); 
            pic++;
            open = 1; // signifies target jpeg file is open
            match = 0; // sets match back to 0 (false) so it can detect the next match to signify closing the writing            
            image=fopen(jpegName, "w"); // write to target file image
        }

        // if file target is still open but no match, then keep writing since you're in the middle of a jpeg
        if (match == 0 && open == 1)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, image);
        }

    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fyi, if this ever starts writing, you're writing the first 512 bytes of each file *twice*.  First when `match==1 && open == 0`, where you set `open = 1;`, open the file, write the data, and set `match = 0;`, then immediate after you check for `match == 0 && open == 1)`, which it will be because you just set it that way, so you write the same block again. The first `fwrite` doesn't appear to need to be there.

Comment: You're right. I removed that. Still doesn't output a jpg.

Comment: Oh, that isn't the only issue, just one I noticed. This needs to be put through a debugger to validate all the assumptions you're making. Ex: You never increment `pic`, so you're always writing to the same target file name `000.jpg`.

Comment: Use a debugger, set breakpoints, single step through your code, compare expected values against found values, etc

Comment: Should be while(fread(buffer,512, 1, file) > 1). I made that change but am now getting: double free or corruption (top) ... 

I'll keep debugging.

Comment: You seem to assume that a jpg-file is always a multiple of 512 bytes since you do not store what fread returns. A jpg-file doesn't need to be a multiple of 512

Comment: You should not fclose if you cannot open the file

Comment: You should initialize `FILE *image` to NULL, just in case since you may do a `fclose(image)` before opening the file.

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something stark, but if all you're trying to do is read a file in 512-byte chunks, checking the first four octets of each chunk for two known preambles, and upon encountering either, open an image file and start dumping until the next chunk that matches closes the file and starts a new one, then about half the posted code isn't needed.

You can use the value of `image` (null or not) to dictate whether a file is opened or not. Further, only write data if a file is opened (`image != NULL)`, and close an existing file if opened before cycling to the next file.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Prefixes of a jpeg file
    static const uint8_t jpeg1[4] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe0};
    static const uint8_t jpeg2[4] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe1};

    // open file for reading
    FILE* file = fopen("card.raw", "r"); // Open the file for reading
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("card.raw");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // target file
    FILE* image = NULL;

    // keep track of jpegs opened
    int pic = 0;

    // while there are bytes to be read in the file
    uint8_t buffer[512];
    size_t n_bytes = 0;
    while( (n_bytes = fread(buffer,1, 512, file)) > sizeof(jpeg1))
    {
        // compares first 4 bytes of buffer segment to jpeg prefixes to determine match
        if( memcmp(buffer, jpeg1, sizeof(jpeg1)) == 0 ||
            memcmp(buffer, jpeg2, sizeof(jpeg2)) == 0)
        {
            // stores the jpeg file name with the # jpeg
            char jpegName[64];
            sprintf(jpegName ,"00%d.jpg" , pic++);

            // match. close current file if present.
            if (image)
                fclose(image);

            // open new image file (sets NULL on failure)
            image = fopen(jpegName, "wb"); // write to target file image
            if (image == NULL)
            {
                perror(jpegName);
                break;
            }
        }

        // write whatever we have for our current bytes
        if (image)
            fwrite(buffer, n_bytes, 1, image);
    }

    // the above loop can exit with a file open (in fact, it is guaranteed
    // if we opened at least one file), so close it if one is active.
    if (image)
        fclose(image);
}
```

Or something similar. This also opens and closes files in binary-mode, and does not write extraneous junk ot the last frame if it was smaller than an even 512 bytes. Finally, it increments `pic` on each file created, and has a (admittedly soft) amount of error checking.

Anyway, hope it helps. Best of luck.