# Why is my jpeg not being recovered, in recoverc.c?

Tags: c

Why is my JPEG not being recovered, in recovering. c?
Not sure what I did wrong, If you see anything that's off please let me know.
I have embedded comments to avoid confusion.

```
typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fimg = fopen("card.raw", "r");

    if (fimg == NULL)
    {
        fclose(fimg);
        fprintf(stderr, "Image does not exist in the cardfile.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // counter to keep track of files found
    int counter = 0; 

    // a buffer of 512 bytes
    BYTE buffer[512];

    BYTE check[4];
    FILE* temp = NULL;

    fread(buffer, 512, 1, fimg);

    // starting bytes for the jpeg files.
    BYTE chkjpg0[4] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe0};
    BYTE chkjpg1[4] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe1};
    char fname[10]; 

    while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, fimg) > 0)
    {
        // check first couple of sequence of the jpg
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            check[i] = buffer[i];

        }

        if (chkjpg0 == 0 || chkjpg1 == 0)
        {   
            // label the files with three digits
            sprintf(fname, "%03d.jpg", counter);

            // next file in line
            temp = fopen(fname, "w");

            // CRANK IT UP
            counter++;

            // new file with buffer
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, temp);
        }
        else if (counter > 0)
        {
            // put jpg into temp
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, temp);            
        }

        fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fimg);
    }   

    fclose(fimg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the format of your raw files, but are the first 512 bytes of the file not significant, and that's why you skip them? What if the data you look for doesn't start on a multiple of 512?

Comment: Also, each iteration of the loop, you read *twice*, discarding every second block you read.

Comment: this is for a pset where the image file is 512 bytes, i was also told the first 4 bytes are empty.

Comment: Is this some kind of school assignment? It keeps on getting asked [since 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bc%5d%20card.raw%20is%3aq), the most recent [2 days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31715614/2564301).

Comment: Yes it for Harvard's intro to computer science class, which they have for free on edx.org.